# Permission issues for importing functions

Tags: python, linux, import, permissions

I have questions regarding permission issues while trying to import functions.

OS: Ubuntu (Linux)
python: 3.7.7.

Assume that there are two users on a PC (one is Admin and the other is Guest user).
I made a library directory, which I put my customized functions.
directory: /home/admin/libary_folder/
customized python file: custom_lib.py

**What I want to do is as follows.**

1. Admin user can do read, write, execute.
2. Guest users can only import the file but cannot see the code.

**What I've tried.**

1. I make the directory with permission as follows.

> chown -R admin:admin /home/admin/libary_folder/
> chmod -R 775 /home/admin/libary_folder/

And it works. (Guest user can import custom_lib.py by using "from cusom_lib import *)
-> However, with this permission Guest user can read Admin's library file.

2. Then, I change the permission as follows.

> chown -R admin:admin /home/admin/libary_folder/
> chmod -R 771 /home/admin/libary_folder/

Now, Guest users cannot read files and cannot import the functions in /home/admin/libary_folder/.

**Here are my questions.**

1. Does "read permission" should necessarily be required to import function?
2. In this case, how I can achieve my goal to make guests user use functions without reading files?

I am not sure that this issue is proper in this board because the problem is a combination of python and Linux. I am struggling with these issues for more than 1-month but still cannot find an answer.

Thank you for reading my long explanations.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Python is an interpreted language you have to be able to "see the code" to execute it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Klaus! 
For someone who faces this issue, I transform the function file (.py) to .pyc or .c  with "read" permission. By doing so, non-admin users can see the code, which cannot be recognized.